# SSL Ldap Connection (ldaps)

Tags: ssl, connection, ldap

I want to connect to ldap over SSL using truststore file.
I'm using the following code:

```
    private DirContext ctxtDir = null;
    Attributes attributes = null;
    ldap_server_url = "ldaps://" + getLdapHostName() + ":"
            + getPort() + "/";
    ldap_base_dn = getBaseDn();
    ldap_user = getLogin();
    ldap_password = getPwd();
    ldap_trust_store_file = "C:\\truststore.jks";
    ldap_trust_store_pwd = getStoreJKSPwd();

    // Set the parameters
    env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, ldap_context_factory);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldap_server_url);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldap_user);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldap_password);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "SSL");

    // Set SSL parameters for Ldaps connection
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ldap_trust_store_file);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",
            ldap_trust_store_pwd);
            // Try to establish the connection
    try {
        // create initial context
        ctxtDir = new InitialDirContext(env);
        attributes = getLdapattributes(ldap_base_dn);
        if (null != attributes) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isAvailable = false;

    }
```

The problem is that i don't want to use the location of the truststore file, i want to use the inputstream (file content), is there any way to do that? like when using SSLContext to esbabish a https connection.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The 'location of the truststore' has nothing to do with 'the input stream'. Please clarify.

Comment: I want to be able to set the trustore parameter value by giving the inputstream and not the location of the file as doing here: 
    `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ldap_trust_store_file);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",
            ldap_trust_store_pwd);`

Comment: I'm not aware of any provision for input streams as you require. The `java.naming.ldap.factory.socket` names the socket factory class as described in the JNDI documentation. What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

[Unbound Ldap SDK](https://www.ldap.com/unboundid-ldap-sdk-for-java) is best latest LDAP API. It also offers `SSLSocketFactory` to establish SSL connection.

```
TrustAllTrustManager manager = new TrustAllTrustManager();
        SSLUtil sslUtil = new SSLUtil(manager);
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;
        try {
            socketFactory = sslUtil.createSSLSocketFactory("TLSv1");
        }
        catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new LDAPException(ResultCode.CANCELED, "An error occured while creating SSL socket factory.");
        }
```

and use this socketFactory as

```
new RoundRobinServerSet(addressesArray, portsArray, socketFactory);
```